# cannot show Dialog in onClick

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog, progress-bar

I have a function for copy file in storage. When I click to copy `Button`, the method copy action will execute. This method below:

```
    public void actionCopy() {
       Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_layout);

       TextView progressTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_title);
       progressTitle.setText("Copying...");
       final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
       progressBar.setMax(listData.size());
       progressBar.setProgress(0);

       dialog.show();

       for(int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
          String value = new CopyDataUtils(listData.get(i)).execute().get();
          progressBar.setProgress(i + 1);
          Log.i(TAG, value);
    }
 }
```

And the CopyDataUtils AsyncTask:

```
public class CopyDataUtils extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private DataItem item;

    public CopyDataUtils(DataItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //...code copy file here
        return ...;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

So My problem is: When actionCopy execute, I want dialog show display. But did not happen. After `for(..)` executed, the dialog was show.
What something wrong?. Is there any suggestion for show dialog before execute multi thread copy data?. 
Sorry my bad english!

**UPDATE:
I tried put dialog to AsyncTask and show it in to method `onPreExecute`. But nothing change.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `new CopyDataUtils(listData.get(i)).execute().get();`. [It blocks the UI thread and waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()).

---

The way you are using `AsyncTask` and dialog is completly wrong. You should move these code to `AsynTask`. On `onPreexecute` you should show dialog. `doInbackground` do you task and at `onPostexecute` hide dialog.

Answer (score 0):

u should show the progress bar in onPreEcecute() of Asynctask

```
   public void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setMessage("your content");
            progressDialog.setMax(listData.size());
            progressDialog.setProgress(0);

       for(int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
          String value = new CopyDataUtils(listData.get(i)).execute().get();

          Log.i(TAG, value);


            progressDialog.show();
        }


 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        return ...;
    }

 @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String s)
    {
        progressBar.setProgress(i + 1);
    }
```

Comment: What is "Calculating directions"?

Comment: i tried you suggest. It's work. But how can i set progress for progressBar?

Comment: http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/06/basic-asynctask-with-progress-bar.html    follow this tutorial it will definately work for u

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `ProgressBar` as a global variable, then update the progress in `onPostExcute()` of AsyncTask

```
public void YouActiviy() {
         ProgressBar progressBar;
         int i = 0;
         public onCreate(){
            ....
         }

         public void actionCopy() {
           ...
           progressBar = (ProgressBar)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
           ...
           dialog.show();
           for(int i = 0; i < listData.size(); i++) {
              new CopyDataUtils(listData.get(i)).execute();
              //progressBar.setProgress(i + 1);
           }
         }

         public class CopyDataUtils extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
             ...
              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                  // update your progressbar here
                   progressBar.setProgress(i++);
                  super.onPostExecute(s);
              }
         }
    }
```

For easy way, you follow this [tutorial](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-download-files-with-progress-dialog/) that will give you the correct way to use `AsyncTask` with `ProgressBar`

Hope this help

Comment: The dialog can not show before `for(..)`. So `setProgress` in `onPostExecute` work fine?

Comment: where and when you call `actionCopy`

Comment: when i click on button `Copy`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set progress in onProgressUpdate(), try this:

```
protected ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private class copyData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //copy data here
    return ...;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        if ((mProgressDialog != null) && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Handle or log or ignore
    } finally {
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
    }
 }
```